# Are astronauts really younger than the rest of us after their trips to space?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation, nasa

I have seen this commented in a million places on social media ([see here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/764900721730022/posts/1004446401108785/?comment_id=1004477564439002&reply_comment_id=1004764581076967&__cft__%5B0%5D=AZV2PLRhE_bgmkDgZdXs7J028qsvC5rR9qF1KbkPv8IFs5lpuviiMm02E6gDuf3xcezeuH5tE-i3VNoLE8oGbfTdvby_DIZHEuAQ9aMzORw5FT79IC3xW4aM9PGRxw7gDkXntqm4_GNm1Q_V28OmC43S&__tn__=R%5D-R) as well as places like [HowStuffWorks](https://science.howstuffworks.com/humans-age-in-space.htm), [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/do-astronauts-age-slower-than-people-on-earth-2015-8), and even [Scott Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Kelly_(astronaut)) makes the claim in [the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/oct/29/scott-kelly-astronaut-interview-space-younger-twin-endurance). Their reasoning for this is pretty straight forward. They claim [time dilation caused by relative velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Time_dilation_caused_by_a_relative_velocity), causes them to age more slowly, thus making them younger. However, unless I am misunderstanding, I believe this fails to take into account [time dilation caused by gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Time_dilation_caused_by_gravity_or_acceleration).

I believe this Wikipedia article on the GPS system says that, due to gravitational time dilation, the clocks on the ground [are slower by about 45.8 microseconds a day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System#:%7E:text=10%2C%20or-,about%20%2B45.8%20%CE%BCs/day,-.%20This%20gravitational%20frequency). Further, while the article does not explicitly say how much the time dilation due to relative velocity is, it does say that the combined sources of time dilation [account for the satellites gaining 38.6 microseconds per day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System#:%7E:text=satellites%20to%20gain%2038.6%20microseconds%20per%20day), suggesting the time dilation from velocity was a mere 7.2 microseconds, unless there are other sources of time dilation of which I am unaware.

Normally, I would just assume the newspapers and social media comments were wrong, but Scott Kelly said it, too, and I want to be sure before I start correcting people on this. So, is there something I am missing? Is it because satellites orbit much higher in the sky? So, are astronauts older or younger after a space flight?

Comment: found this in a popularized article "after spending six months on the ISS, astronauts have aged about 0.005 seconds less than the rest of us." https://www.businessinsider.com/do-astronauts-age-slower-than-people-on-earth-2015-8

Comment: the quote must be from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Time_dilation_caused_by_a_relative_velocity

Comment: I am pretty sure that every returned astronaut in history has been younger than some of "the rest of us" and older than others.

Comment: The section "Combined effect of velocity and gravitational time dilation" on that Wikipedia page has a useful graph.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the satellites are in much higher orbits. Keep in mind that higher orbits move slower and lower orbits move faster.

Astronauts are at essentially the same potential as we are. The international space station only is around 6% farther from the center of the Earth than the surface is. So the gravitational contribution to time dilation is tiny. But the kinematic contribution is large, since the space station is in orbit and we are not.

GPS satellites orbit much farther and slower. So the gravitational contribution is much larger, while the kinematic contribution is much smaller.

Comment: but we are accelerated and astronauts are in free fall, I am not that sure who spends more proper time after several orbits

Comment: *"But the kinematic contribution is large..."* Large compared to what?

Comment: I am not sure it's reasonable to say "well, the contribution is small" when the point of comparison is microseconds per day, a few parts per billion. I'm not disagreeing with your conclusion, but you don't give enough context for me to trust comfortably. I always have to look up the altitude of geosynchronous orbits (though it's several Earth radii). There are also sneaky effects (like the absence of time dilation differences across the geoid, because gravitational potential and rotational speed give opposite contributions) that may or may not come into play.